# Monotone likelihood ratio implies stochastic dominance

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

I am studying the following proposition:

> Let $P_0,P_1$ be probability measures on $(X,\Sigma)$ having real-valued densities $f_0,f_1$ with respect to measure $\mu$. Suppose there exist a measurable function $T:X\to \mathbb R$ and a function $g:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty]$ such that
>
> 1. $\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}=g(T(x))$ on $D$
> 2. $g$ is nondecreasing on $T(D)$
>
> where $D=\{x\in X: f_0(x)>0 \text{ or } f_1(x)>0\}$, and we use the convention $\frac{c}{0}=\infty$ for the ratio $\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}$. Then
>
> $$\int_{T(x)<k} f_1(x) d\mu\leq \int_{T(x)<k} f_0(x) d\mu $$
>
> for all $k\in \mathbb R$.

**Proof.** If $\mu(D)=0$ then $f_0=f_1=0$ a.s., so WLOG $\mu(D)>0$. Let $\alpha=\sup\{t\in T(D):g(t)\leq 1\}$. Note that $\alpha>-\infty$, for otherwise $g(t)>1$ for all $t\in T(D)$, which implies $f_1>f_0$ on $D$, and hence $\int f_1 d\mu>\int f_0 d\mu=1$, a contradiction. One can check that
$$T(x)>\alpha\implies f_1(x)\geq f_0(x)$$

$$T(x)<\alpha\implies f_1(x)\leq f_0(x)$$

However to finish the proof it seems we need to assume that $T(\mu)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Is this correct?